# How do I use a behavioral voltage source to mathematically divide a voltage within an AC analysis?

Tags: ltspice

When I try to do this, I usually get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the program thinks the output is -infinity dB (0V) for some reason. Strangely, before I saved the file it was outputting 0dB (1V) as expected. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Why don't you just plot v(a)*v(b)/v(c) but, be aware that when v(c)=0 you will get an overflow.

Comment: @Andyaka that would make sense, but the thing is v(c) is never zero in the simulation I'm showing in this question. Hence my confusion

Comment: All I see/know/have_access_to is "AC1" and that implies an AC signal doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a small signal analysis.  The B-source is simply going to multiply and divide the operating points for the `a`, `b`, and `c` nodes, which are all zero.  Can you expand on what you intend to accomplish as there might be an alternative approach?  Absent that, the best way would be to take @Andyaka 's advice which will do the math on each output datapoint instead of just the operating points.

Comment: In SPICE an AC analysis is a linear analysis. It assumes all components are linear. How exactly it deals with a nonlinear controlled source you'll have to read in the documents. Maybe it will discard nonlinear components, maybe it will linearize about an operating point, maybe it will just output 0. Read the docs to find out.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks, this makes more sense now. I didn't realize BV sources acted on the DC operating points of the voltages they call on during AC analysis, as opposed to the voltages' AC amplitude at a given frequency. Andy's comments make more sense now too.

What I'm trying to do is complicated but essentially I'm simulating a transformer and a load, and I want to have a second identical transformer next to the first whose AC source compensates for the inductance of the transformer at high frequencies to provide a constant load current, by dividing the 2nd source by the 1st load current.

Comment: @burkesm2  OK, I understand.  See if you can use a combination of the controlled linear sources (E-source, G-source, F-source, H-source) to accomplish what you want.  Look at the built-in LTspice help to see how to use them.  Alternatively, can you do your analysis using a transient simulation with SINE sources and use LTspice's FFT function?  Otherwise, if you get stuck then might be worth posting a fresh question for your specific problem.

Comment: @SteKulov I doesn't look like the E/G/F/H sources provide any utility that a BV source can't. Unfortunately I can't do my analysis from transient to FFT. I posted a new question. Feel free to check it out: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/664313/in-ltspice-how-do-i-create-a-voltage-source-with-a-piecewise-frequency-dependen

Comment: @burkesm2  The E/G/F/H sources can be used in `.ac` because they are linear.  That's what's different.

Answer (score 1):

It was already determined in the comments that for your specific inputs, the output would result in zero because the DC operating points for all your inputs were zero.  However, if you start to adjust the DC operating points, it's not immediately clear what the result is.  So, I did some more digging into this.

I started with just the simple `V(a)*V(b)` behavioral circuit and took a sampling of data with various mixtures of AC and DC values.  The general result I got from the samples looked to be in this form:

$$
\begin{align*}
V_{out(DC)} &= V_{a(DC)} \cdot V_{b(DC)} \\
V_{out(AC)} &= V_{a(DC)} \cdot V_{b(AC)} + V_{a(AC)} \cdot V_{b(DC)}
\end{align*}
$$

The DC result is obviously the direct result of the behavioral equation.  The AC result's form reminded me much of the "product rule" in calculus.  And that makes sense because in small-signal analysis, the slope at the operating point is used for the conductance.  So I took the derivative of `V(a)*V(b)` and it ends up being the same:

$$
V_{out}' = V_{a} \cdot V_{b}' + V_{a}' \cdot V_{b}
$$

where the primes are the AC values and non-primes are the DC values.

---

I extended this to three variables by trying the `V(a)*V(b)/V(c)` behavioral equation to check if this holds.  The derivative is:

$$
V_{out}' = \frac{V_{a}' \cdot V_{b} \cdot V_{c} + V_{b}' \cdot V_{a} \cdot V_{c} - V_{a} \cdot V_{b} \cdot V_{c}'}{V_{c}^2}
$$

If we take this example:
[image]

and plug those values into the equation:
$$
V_{out}' = \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 - 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3}{4^2} = \frac{12 + 16 - 18}{16} = \frac{10}{16} = 625 \text{mV}
$$

Then running the simulation to validate, we get the same result:

[image]