# In LTspice, how do I create a voltage source with a piecewise frequency dependence in an AC analysis?

Tags: ltspice

I would like to run an AC analysis with a voltage source whose voltage varies with frequency according to the following piecewise plot:

[image]

I've heard it's impossible to have a frequency dependent voltage source in LTspice. I'm able to get around this for the first part of this curve using this technique:

[image]

Above, B1's voltage increases with frequency at 20dB/decade, just like the first part of the piecewise voltage function I'm going for. The second part is of course very simple - just a standard small signal AC voltage source.

I'm struggling with the third part of the piecewise, as there's no simple circuit I know of that creates a voltage that falls off at -10dB/decade. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to integrate these various sources into one piecewise source. I could brute force this by having three separate sims, one for each source, but I would prefer a more elegant solution. Any tips on these issues?

Comment: What do you expect to gain from varying the voltage in an AC analysis? It's a linear analysis so you might as well just scale the output, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have a diode, BJT, and MOSFET in my sim. Are they treated as linear for the purpose of an AC analysis?

Comment: That is my understanding. The algorithm finds the operating point and linearizes about that operating point, and scales based on the claimed input amplitude.

Comment: Yes, the `.ac` simulation is a small signal analysis which implies linearization.  See the built-in LTspice page for the `.ac` command ([web archive version here](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/AC_analysis.htm)).  I think you had a bit of an XY problem going on.  Anyway, sounds like you just need to use a FREQ table.  I'll post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've heard it's impossible to have a frequency dependent voltage
> source in LTspice.

I don't know where you heard this from.  Anyway, I believe you just need to use a "FREQ table", which is simply a way to make a piecewise-linear source in the frequency domain.  [It's not in any of the official LTspice documentation](https://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29), but LTspice can do it since it touts PSpice model compatibility and this feature is originally a PSpice feature.

Here is an example that plots your desired frequency response:
[image]

In this example consisting of only 4 points it's easy to define the FREQ table directly on the component within the schematic.  If your target function requires a bunch more points, it might be easier to define the component as a SPICE directive and have it as a text block off to the side using the `+` symbol to allow you to continue a super long line horizontal line vertically ([see the last entry of the first table her](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/A_General_Structure_and_Conventions.htm)e).  If it's even BIGGER, then it's probably better throwing it into a subcircuit and `.lib`-ing it into the simulation.  The answers to this previous question tackle some of that more nuanced stuff if you're interested:

[LTspice: tables for parameterized passive components... why not?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/657820/)

---

It's worth noting that you can also define much smoother curves in the frequency domain using the `Laplace` feature.  Both `FREQ` and `Laplace` suffer from artifacts when used in transient simulations because LTspice has to compute an IFFT to get the impulse response.  However, Laplace is usually more well-behaved in that respect.  If you're just doing `.ac` analysis, then you don't have to worry about that aspect, but if necessary more info can be found in the LTspice Help under ["B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources"](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/B_Arbitrary_behavioral_voltage_or_current_sources_.htm) (duplicated below):

> If an optional Laplace transform is defined, that transform is applied
> to the result of the behavioral current or voltage. The Laplace
> transform must be a function solely of s. The Boolean XOR operator, ^,
> is understood to mean exponentiation, **, when used in a Laplace
> expression. The frequency response at frequency f is found by
> substituting s with sqrt(-1)*2*pi*f. The time domain behavior is found
> from the sum of the instantaneous current(or voltage) with the
> convolution of the history of this current(or voltage) with the
> impulse response. Numerical inversion of a Laplace transfer function
> to the time domain impulse response is a potentially compute-bound
> process and a topic of current numerical research. In LTspice, the
> impulse response is found from the FFT of a discrete set points in
> frequency domain response. This process is prone to the usual
> artifacts of FFT's such as spectral leakage and picket fencing that is
> common to discrete FFT's. LTspice uses a proprietary algorithm that
> exploits that it has an exact analytical expression for the frequency
> domain response and chooses points and windows to cause such artifacts
> to diffract precisely to zero. However, LTspice must guess an
> appropriate frequency range and resolution. It is recommended that the
> LTspice first be allowed to make a guess at this. The length of the
> window and number of FFT data points used will be reported in the .log
> file. You can then adjust the algorithm's choices by explicitly
> setting nfft and window length. The reciprocal of the value of the
> window is the frequency resolution. The value of nfft times this
> resolution is the highest frequency considered. Note that the
> convolution of the impulse response with the behavioral source is also
> potentially a compute bound process.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This isn't necessary, but do you know if there's any way to combine the FREQ table and Laplace functions? Like let's say I want the BV source to be defined by a FREQ table from 10kHz to 10Meg, then by a Laplace function from 10Meg to 100Meg.

Comment: @burkesm2 Hmmm...I don't believe so as the `FREQ` command overrides the `Laplace` command. The best workaround I can think of is to simulate your 10Meg to 100Meg section using Laplace, and then take the datapoints and export them into a FREQ table which you can add to the end of your existing 10k to 10Meg table. So you're kind of "sampling" the Laplace function in a sense and using the samples to extend your table. If you want finer resolution, run your "sampling" simulation at a higher points per decade.  Go to [File]->[Export data as text].  You might have to use Notepad++ to add `+` signs.

Comment: @burkesm2 Here's a quick example.  B1 is a full Laplace function.  B2 is your original table.  B3 is made using a SPICE directive.  It's made using the table data from B2 from 10k to 10Meg PLUS data from a previous run of B1 from 10Meg to 100Meg.  Result of B3 is plotted as `V(out3)`.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr8Vz.png

Comment: That makes sense, I'll give that a try soon. Thanks again!!